# Missing entry points in USER32.dll stops program from launching, C++, VS2015

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015

I'm writing a C++ program using **VS2015** (Platform Toolset v140, Target Platform 8.1) on a Windows 10 machine, and my program ran just fine on Windows 7, 8 and 10 up until recently.

After adding touch support using [`GetPointerInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454885.aspx), I get this pop-up error immediately on execution on Windows 7 machines:

> Unable to find an entry point named GetPointerInfo in USER32.dll

MS clearly states that `GetPointerInfo()` is only supported on Win8 and up, and that's all right, but I don't want to break my program's compatibility with Windows 7 altogether.

I assume Windows 7's version of `USER32.DLL` doesn't containing the function at all, but adding runtime checks in my program (i.e. only calling `GetPointerInfo()` if `IsWindows8OrGreater()` returns true) doesn't do the trick.

In fact, merely compiling my program with any reference to `GetPointerInfo()` will break Win7 compatibility, no matter if the function is actually called or not. The program won't even enter `WinMain()`, it just throws me that message and quits.

Again, on Windows 8 and up, everything is working just fine.

How do I solve this?

I have Googled for half a day, but having very little knowledge of DLLs, linker and compiler settings, I obviously don't even know how to phrase my searches because I have come up empty so far.

I have tried both Multi-threaded (/MT) and Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) as my Runtime Library.

I have also tried enabling and disabling Function-Level Linking, but the result remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

> I assume Windows 7's version of USER32.dll doesn't containing the function at all

That is correct.

> but adding runtime checks in my program (i.e. only calling GetPointerInfo on IsWindows8OrGreater) doesn't do the trick. :(

It does if you load the function dynamically at runtime, either by using your linker's [delay-loading feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx), or using [`GetProcAddress()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx) directly in your code (the linker's delay loader uses `GetProcAddress()` internally for you).

> In fact, merely compiling my program with any reference to GetPointerInfo will break Win7 compatibility, no matter if the funcion is actually called or not.

That error happens only if you static-link to the function at compile-time without using the linker's delay-load feature.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.

GetProcAddress() is a great method for me.
I have encounter the same problem.
And I have referenced [this website about using GetProcAddress()](https://blog.benoitblanchon.fr/getprocaddress-like-a-boss/)!

1.write some definitions

```
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *GetPointerInfoProc)(UINT32,POINTER_INFO *);
```

2.delay loading library

`HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(TEXT("user32.dll"));
 GetPointerInfoProc GetPointerInfo = (GetPointerInfoProc )GetProcAddress(hModule, "GetPointerInfo");`

3.call method

```
GetPointerInfo(pointerId,&pointerInfo)
```